# Autofac.Core.DependencyResolutionException: None of the constructors found with 'Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.DefaultConstructorFinder'

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, autofac

I tried to Identity service on **autofac** but I have got that error.

I am using **.NET CORE 3.1.1** version.

> Autofac.Core.DependencyResolutionException: **An exception was thrown while activating** Business.Concrete.AuthManager -> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1[[Core.Entities.Concrete.ApplicationUser, Core, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]] -> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.UserStore`9[[Core.Entities.Concrete.ApplicationUser, Core, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null],[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityRole, Microsoft.Extensions.Identity.Stores, Version=3.1.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60],[DataAccess.Concrete.EntityFramework.Context.**MyApplicationDbContext**, DataAccess, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null],[System.String, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e],[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUserClaim`1[[System.String, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]], Microsoft.Extensions.Identity.Stores, Version=3.1.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60],[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUserRole`1[[System.String, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]], Microsoft.Extensions.Identity.Stores, Version=3.1.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60],[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUserLogin`1[[System.String, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]], Microsoft.Extensions.Identity.Stores, Version=3.1.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60],[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUserToken`1[[System.String, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]], Microsoft.Extensions.Identity.Stores, Version=3.1.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60],[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityRoleClaim`1[[System.String, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]], Microsoft.Extensions.Identity.Stores, Version=3.1.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60]].
>    ---> Autofac.Core.DependencyResolutionException: None of the constructors found with 'Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.DefaultConstructorFinder' on type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.UserStore`9[Core.Entities.Concrete.ApplicationUser,Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityRole,DataAccess.Concrete.EntityFramework.Context.**MyApplicationDbContext**,System.String,Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUserClaim`1[System.String],Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUserRole`1[System.String],Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUserLogin`1[System.String],Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUserToken`1[System.String],Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityRoleClaim`1[System.String]]' can be invoked with the available services and parameters:
>   Cannot resolve parameter 'DataAccess.Concrete.EntityFramework.Context.MyApplicationDbContextcontext' of constructor 'Void .ctor(DataAccess.Concrete.EntityFramework.Context.MyApplicationDbContext, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityErrorDescriber)'.
>      at Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.ReflectionActivator.GetValidConstructorBindings(IComponentContext context, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
>      at Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.ReflectionActivator.ActivateInstance(IComponentContext context, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
>      at Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Activate(IEnumerable`1 parameters, Object& decoratorTarget)
>      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>      at Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Activate(IEnumerable`1 parameters, Object& decoratorTarget)
>      at Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Execute()
>      at Autofac.Core.Resolving.ResolveOperation.GetOrCreateInstance(ISharingLifetimeScope currentOperationScope, IComponentRegistration registration, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
>      at Autofac.Core.Resolving.ResolveOperation.ResolveComponent(IComponentRegistration registration, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
>      at Autofac.Core.Resolving.ResolveOperation.Execute(IComponentRegistration registration, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
>      at Autofac.Core.Lifetime.LifetimeScope.ResolveComponent(IComponentRegistration registration, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
>      at Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.TryResolveService(IComponentContext context, Service service, IEnumerable`1 parameters, Object& instance)
>      at Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.ResolveOptionalService(IComponentContext context, Service service, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
>      at Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.ResolveOptional(IComponentContext context, Type serviceType, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
>      at Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.ResolveOptional(IComponentContext context, Type serviceType)
>      at Autofac.Extensions.DependencyInjection.AutofacServiceProvider.GetService(Type serviceType)
>      at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.GetService(IServiceProvider sp, Type type, Type requiredBy, Boolean isDefaultParameterRequired)
>      at lambda_method(Closure , IServiceProvider , Object[] )
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerActivatorProvider.<>c__DisplayClass4_0.b__0(ControllerContext controllerContext)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerFactoryProvider.<>c__DisplayClass5_0.g__CreateController|0(ControllerContext controllerContext)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|19_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)

This is my AutofacBusinessModule.cs

```
namespace Business.DependencyResolvers.Autofac
{
    public class AutofacBusinessModule : Module
    {
        protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
        {


            builder.RegisterType<AuthManager>().As<IAuthService>();
            builder.RegisterType<UserServiceManager>().As<IUserService>();

            builder.RegisterType<JwtHelper>().As<ITokenHelper>();

            // ------  What should I write in this part for Identity implementation? -------

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I suspect you'd need to mimic the default implementation:  https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/master/src/Identity/Core/src/IdentityServiceCollectionExtensions.cs

Comment: @timur No, this is the first time I see this application. I found that similar problem on stackoverflow but not work with .InstancePerApiRequest(); without work. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42139457/none-of-the-constructors-found-with-autofac-core-activators-reflection-defaultc#

Comment: @timur builder.RegisterType<EntitiesContext>().AsSelf()
           .As<IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>>().InstancePerApiRequest(); this code bellow was without InstancePerApiRequest() worked. Is that required InstancePerApiRequest ?

Comment: I'd keep it exactly the way it is in the original for starters. Yours probably will be slightly different lifetime description, but as long as the intent is similar I reckon

Comment: @timur what exactly does InstancePerApiRequest() do ? In addition, this extension is not available to my application. Instead it's got InstancePerRequest().